# Does sharing in android require app verificationform from Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

using this source https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing I am trying to implement share via facebook from my app.It will work fine with app_Id provided by this project but when i replace the id with my own  its not working.Do i need to add preveleges in my facebook app for achiving "post to wall" task just i test mode?

```
facebook.publishMessage(null,"http://mothersgroupapp.com/", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you need to submit a facebook review for you to use the publish_actions permission. But you can test your app now if you are logged in as the Admin/tester/developer of the app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: What does it say in the logs? Can you try to fill-up the publishMessage params with real values instead of nulls? That might be the one causing it. I remember it happened to once.

Comment: there is no error, I have tried with all real values as well

Comment: You might wanna consider using other libraries. You're using a very old library and it's not being maintained anymore. I recommend https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook